# react-native update state automatically

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am using mobx to pass state.

First I store some data to mobx. 
For example, in the FirstScreen, I store some data using mobx: `store.data = 'somedata'`

Then, I want to pass this data in my SecondScreen, so I do:

```
<Button onPress={()=> this.setState({putsomeData:store.data})}>
   <Text>update</Text>
</Button>
```

This would work fine. But is there a way I could listen to the update and automatically update the state without using the button?

Comment: Setting your state in a lifecycle method does not fit your question? For example in `componentDidMount()` of the SecondScreen.

Answer (score 0):

in mobx you can use `@observer` to change your state based on the value

ref. https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html